# Algorithm for placing circles of Diameter d around the edge of another circle with diameter D

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Hi i'm struggling with what i think may be simple maths. I need to place circles of a small size around the edge of larger circle.. is there an algorithm to calculate the angle for each small circle from the x-axis, counter clockwise? then using this angle i can find the Cartesian coordinates (x,y) of the enter of each circle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about elementary trigonometry, not computer science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circles centers form isosceles triangle with base of length $2r$ and arms of length $R+r$, so
$ \tan (\frac{\beta}{2}) = \frac { r}{ r+R} $ hance $\beta = 2\arctan(\frac{r}{r+R}) $

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. You gave me an idea to find the answer, which was to use the base of the isosceles as you said which would be 2r and then the arm lengths are equal to R. I then split it down the middle to get a right angled triangle. So have the opposite(r) and hypotenuse(R), so it was a matter of using 2 * sin-1(o/h). I think you found the adjacent and used the toa of the sohcahtoa :). Thanks so much